# Entity Framework Pascal Case

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have camelCase column names in my DB. I want EF to bring them over as Pascal case, short of modifying the T4 template how can I achieve this.

Ideally I could just toggle an option at EDMX creation time. I do not want to modify the T4 template. Anyone try/achieve this before.

I am using EF 5.0

Comment: This SO Question may have some info for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9726718/1439998

Comment: I appreciate you pulling that solution up. I would rather have a setting somewhere then have a console app go through and rename things for me.

Comment: Fair enough. However, based upon all of the other solutions to work around the issue, the setting may not exist. Good luck in your search!

Comment: MS is dropping support for EDMX files going forward.  It is recommended to use the Code First approach, as that will be the only method available in future EF versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isnt a way to do this through configuation. I had to create a custom t4 template and nuget package to distribute this among my team.

Comment: Could you share the template?

Comment: @ataravati, sorry I no longer have access to the template